# using python unable to push data from dataframe to teradata table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

using python unable to push data from dataframe to teradata table
I have created table and same list of columns in teradata which are present in dataframe
but when i try to push data there were few different types of errors

I have tried below like snippets

```
      import pandas as pd
      import teradatasql
      from google.cloud import bigquery

     client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('path/to/service/account/key.json')
     query_job = client.query('SELECT * FROM bigquery_table')
     df = query_job.to_dataframe()
     con = teradatasql.connect(host='teradata_host', user='username', password='password')

     with con.cursor() as cur:
           cur.execute("CREATE TABLE teradata_table (col1 VARCHAR(100), col2 INTEGER, col3 FLOAT)")

     for index, row in df.iterrows():
         query = "INSERT INTO teradata_table VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
         cur.execute(query, tuple(row))
     con.commit()
```

But am getting few different errors :

```
  OperationalError: [Version 17.20.0.19] [Session 31039764] [Teradata Database] [Error 3707] Syntax error, 
   expected something like a 'CHECK' keyword between ',' and the 'index' keyword.
```

and even I tried with `to_sql` as well but same issue

```
      df.to_sql('teradata_table',con=con,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

But am getting below error:

```
  OperationalError: [Version 17.20.0.19] [Session 31051994] [Teradata Database] 
 [Error 3707] Syntax error, expected something like '(' between the 'type' keyword and '='.
```

Comment: Are you perhaps using `sqlalchemy` 2.x? The `teradatasql` driver 17.20.0.19 still requires `sqlalchemy` 1.4.x

Comment: @Fred: No am not using sqlalchemy , i have to push data to teradata table from bigquery table

Comment: the word "index" is nowhere in the SQL you are showing.

Comment: @Andrew : yeah thats what am wondering even i dont have column like index

Comment: Pandas to_sql will use SQLAlchemy which in turn will need teradatasqlalchemy (for teradatasql dialect). Generally we try to avoid single-row operations in a loop, but I don't understand why the error for cursor.execute complains about something not present in the query string. May want to look at the database logs to get a clearer picture of what the client is sending as the request text. Possibly also validate what is being sent as the "sequence of values" although this error specifically points at the submitted query and not the parameter values.

Comment: @Fred : Thanks for swift reply. You are suggesting me to go with sqlalchemy?

Comment: No, just saying if you wanted to use `to_sql` you should be aware. Normally we try to avoid converting to/from dataframe unless you are actually processing the data in some way on the client. If you are just copying data, maybe consider doing a cursor.fetchmany from the source and cursor.executemany on the target with a reasonably large batch arraysize.